# JsonNodeをセットしたいです。

Tags: java, junit

JunitテストのためJsonNodeのデータをセットしたいですが、簡単にセットできるPatternがありますか？

```
Test test = new Test();
JsonNode node = JsonNode.class; // ここにJsonNodeデータをセットしたい 
test.setJsonNode(node);
```

Comment: 質問の意味がよく分かりません...JSONファイルから`JsonNode`インスタンスをつくりたいということですかね？

Comment: はい、このところに `test.setJsonNode(node);` nodeはJsonNode typeの値が必要ので！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> はい、このところに test.setJsonNode(node); nodeはJsonNode typeの値が必要ので！

であれば、こんな感じでいいのでは？

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(new File("test.json"));
```

Comment: Koheiさんのおかけで、テストは問題ないで動かった。